# How to download a image that's on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webrtc

I wrote this webRTC app which takes photos with different filters added onto it. When I click on the click button, the frame from the webRTC video feed is loaded onto the canvas on the right side.

[image]

**HTML Code** -

```
<video id="vid" autoplay="true"></video>
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
<button id="btn1" onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="change()">Change Filter</button>
<button id="btn3" onclick="snap()" ng-click="random()">Click</button>
```

The function I've written to snap the picture onto the canvas after adding the filter is as follows

```
function snap() 
    {
    canvas.className = '';
    if (findex != 0)
    canvas.classList.add(filters[findex]);
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
```

How can I allow the user to download the image onto the computer from the canvas with the filters after the photo has been clicked ?

Comment: You can do this by using the `.toDataURL()` method on the `canvas` element, using an `a` tag. Here is an example (not mine): http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/7PRNN/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It does not allow me to download the image from the canvas after the effect was applied. toDataURL() downloads the image from the canvas without the effects. How do i bind the filters to the images before downloading ?

Comment: You will need to apply the filter to the `canvas` element directly. Then download, this method downloads exactly what is on the context of the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `.toDataURL()` method on the `canvas` element. And then apply this to the `download` attribute to an `<a>` tag. We can add an anchor tag around the image:

```
<a>
    <canvas width="300" height="300" id="canvas"></canvas>
</a>
```

Now for the clicking on the canvas, we adjust the `download` and `href` of the `<a>` parent:

```
$('#canvas').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().attr('href', document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL());
     $(this).parent().attr('download', "myPicture.png");    
});
```

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljrf7uxm/)

Comment: Thank you. This solved my first problem but the image that downloads does not have the respective css-webkit filter I've applied.

Comment: @JashJacob This is because it saves the original data on the canvas. You will have to apply the filter directly to the context of the canvas. The canvas is not able to access the CSS filters to bind to it. You will need to modify `ctx.getImageData`. For basic effects it's not hard (such as gray-scale). What is your filter doing?

Comment: I'm doing something like these -webkit-filter: contrast(1.3) grayscale(0.6) saturate(10) sepia(0.4); and  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(200%);

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using Concrete.js, which is a lightweight HTML5 Canvas Framework that does peripheral stuff like this, including downloads.  You would just do:

```
canvas.download({
  fileName: 'my-file.png'
});
```