# download image from canvas by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to download loaded image by following code but this is not working (not downloading )
I need to download loaded image in Local Storage of my computer
I am getting  Error  -> security Exception

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img  id="imageId" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Eaxq_eRyitzuD_wcptI_RBva0CiqzWPztZolEDfKrdftel4ENSf2XinyJyjPecUrJQ" >
    <button onclick="storeImageIntoLocal()">Copy Image </button>
    <script>
      function storeImageIntoLocal() {
        var img=document.getElementById('imageId');
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = (img.width+50);
        canvas.height = (img.height+15);
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        body.appendChild(canvas);
      
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
     
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // this is not working 
     alert("converted");
     
     localStorage.setItem("image",dataURL);// this is not working 

        //    var base64dataFinal= dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried that one also but not able to download image

Comment: Please read about [minimal reproducible examples of issues you are facing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Adding to what Igor said, it's really helpful mentioning what you had tried so far, including other answers, and mentioning them and the errors you've got

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage.setItem("image", dataURL);`  is not expected to trigger a file download. This is a plain wrong API to invoke in a first place.

You need to create an `<a>` html element and assign its `href` attribute the `dataURL` value, then trigger a `click()` on it.
See this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26050821/482868

---

```
var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.href = dataURL;
downloadLink.download = 'myImage.png';

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

Comment: i dont want to create any new tag into html code ,
i want to save it by using javascript or convert into base64 format this canvas loaded image

Comment: "i dont want to create any new tag into html code". it's created and is deleted immediately after download is triggered. if you don't want to create a tag -- good luck finding an alternative (if you search in SO more, you'll find _everyone_ does that)

Comment: i meant to say that i dont want to create any other tag into my HTML code by writing some HTML code any new tag creation can be done by using javascript

Comment: @user8767901 well, the code i provided does create and removes the tag dynamically -- see `appendChild` and `removeChild` invocations. It's a phantom/ephemeral tag.

Comment: this is not working just because  =>  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  
getting exception for above statement Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.


after this statement none of the written code is getting execute

Comment: @user8767901 not sure why you think it's not working.  The code does work totally fine in my project: https://github.com/another-guy/randvizer/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L160

Answer (score 0):

You should create new image via Image().
Here is solution:

```js
function storeImageIntoLocal() {
     var img=document.getElementById('imageId');
     var imgI = new Image();
     imgI.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
     imgI.src = img.src;
     var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
     canvas.width = (img.width+50);
     canvas.height = (img.height+15);

     var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     body.appendChild(canvas);
      
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     ctx.drawImage(imgI, 0, 0);
     
     var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"); 
     alert("converted");

     localStorage.setItem("image",dataURL);
 }
```

This code works for me

Comment: thank u for this ans but this s not helpful for me ,it is not working

Comment: @Dmitry, this code does not result in a _file download_. It only stores it in a localStorage which is the same thing as the original code.

Comment: can we get base64 format of this canvas loaded image

Comment: above function canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg") throwing an exception